# SAPUI5: How to add custom functionality to column menu of ui.table?

Tags: uitableview, data-binding, formatting, sapui5, number-formatting

I'd like to give my users the chance to reformat table cells after data has been loaded into the table. I thought a neat way to do this, is adding the functionality to the column menu. So when clicking on a table column, the menu appends with the standard "filtering, sorting" but also has a row called "formatting" which provides a few options (E.g. format a numeric cell from 55555,55 to 55.555,55)

Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to add a new row to my column menu. My sorting and filtering is added like this:

```
oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
    var columnName = context.getObject().columnId;
    return new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label:columnName,
        template: columnName,
        sortProperty: columnName,
        filterProperty: columnName,
    });
});
```

How do I add new lines/functionalities to the column menu?

**Update**

This is how my table looks like in xml view:

```
 <table:Table id="uploadData" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" rowSelectionChange="tableRowSelectionChange" enableCellFilter="true" fixedColumnCount="0" enableBusyIndicator="true" customData="{Type: 'sap.ui.core.CustomData', key:'table-style-type', value:'custom-styled',  writeToDom: true }">
        <table:extension>
                <m:Button icon="sap-icon://download" press="onDataExportXLS" align="Right" />
        </table:extension>

        <table:columns>
                <!-- Columns dynamically created in controller -->
        </table:columns>
        <table:rows>
                <!-- Rows created in controller -->
        </table:rows>
</table:Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sap.ui.table.Column` has an aggregation called `menu` just for this. It accepts any custom menu items which are shown when clicking on a Column. This aggregation takes `sap.ui.unified.Menu` control.

In the `select` function of the `MenuItem` aggregation, you can write the function to handle what needs to be done when the menu item is selected

[sap.ui.table.Column documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Column/controlProperties)

[sap.ui.unified.Menu documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Menu)

Check it in [this sample here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Menus/preview) and [its code here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Menus/code), click on the **Quantity** column and you will see a *My custom menu entry*

A snippet of the code here in XML,

```
<Column id="quantity" width="6rem" hAlign="End" sortProperty="Quantity">
    <m:Label text="Quantity" />
    <template>
        <m:Label text="{ path: 'Quantity', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer'}" />
    </template>
    <menu>
        <u:Menu ariaLabelledBy="quantity">
            <u:items>
                <u:MenuItem text="My custom menu entry" select="onQuantityCustomItemSelect" />
                <u:MenuItem text="Sort" select="onQuantitySort" icon="sap-icon://sort" />
            </u:items>
        </u:Menu>
    </menu>
</Column>
```

The code in JS,

```
var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: "Some column Name",
    menu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
        items: [new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
            text: "My custom menu",
            select: function (oEvent) {
                pressEventOnItem(oEvent);
            })
        ]
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'm using a ui.table which gets dynamically filled by "bindColumns()" in the Controller.. so I tried adding your code to my xml view but it doesn't work.. I get an error saying ""Element sap.ui.unified.Menu#__menu0" is not valid for aggregation "columns" of Element sap.ui.table.Table#..." 
I will add my xml code for the table to my question, maybe that helps? Sorry, would love to hear how I can implement it with that structure!

Comment: Ok, so I simply added your code for all of the columns
Now I have one more question, my "sortProperty" and "filterProperty" are gone now, they're overwritten I asume. How do I get them back?

Comment: In you code of bindColumns, just add the `menu` code after the `filterProperty: columnName,`

Comment: that's what I did!

Comment: oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
      var columnName = context.getObject().columnId;
      // var technicalName = context.getObject().technicalId;
      return new sap.ui.table.Column({

       label:columnName,
       template: columnName,
       filterProperty: columnName,
       sortProperty: columnName,
menu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
        items: [....]
      })
     })

that's how it looks like now!